# Please HELP ME get rid of this voice on my computer!

Tags: sound

Baby hit something and now whenever I roll over something with my mouse or type this voice says the letter or the name of the webpage or if I adjust the volume it tells me what volume (i.e. "volume setting 29") It's driving me nuts!!! It's like the baby enabled a hearing impaired setting or something. I have Ubuntu 14.04 and Firefox. Help?

Comment: Not sure why this question was down voted. Anyone who had kids or pets would understand.

Answer (score 1):

This is called Orca, aka the screen reader.  These options are always going to be found in accessibility options.

The shortcut to enable, and I assume disable, is Alt + Super + S.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Accessibility

Comment: Hey, thanks. Sorry to anyone that was irritated at this duplicate, if I had known it was ORCA then maybe I would have known what to look for . . . Thanks again.